# yii CActiveRecord with()

Tags: database, foreach, yii

I have the following code and the when I call my find method it shows me this: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in CActiveFinder at line 784:

```
$pk=array();
784             foreach($this->_pkAlias as $name=>$alias)
785             {
786                 if(isset($row[$alias]))
787                     $pk[$name]=$row[$alias];
788                 else    // no matching related objects
789                     return null;
790             }
791             $pk=serialize($pk);
```

It fails when it reaches this code:

```
$objCampanie = $modelCampanii->with('stocs')->findAll();
```

Relations from class Campanii:

```
 * @property Stoc[] $stocs
* @property Vanzari[] $vanzaris
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'stocs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Stoc', 'id_campanie'),
        'vanzaris' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Vanzari', 'id_campanie'),
    );
}
```

Relations from class Stoc

```
* @property Produse $codProdus
* @property Campanii $idCampanie
* @property Vanzari[] $vanzaris
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'codProdus' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Produse', 'cod_produs'),
        'idCampanie' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Campanii', 'id_campanie'),
        'vanzaris' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Vanzari', 'cod_produs'),
    );
}
```

Where is the problem? Why does it not retrieves my code?

Table structure:
Campanii:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campanii` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nume` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`data_comanda` date NOT NULL,
`data_scadenta` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Stoc:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stoc` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_campanie` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cod_produs` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`cantitate` int(11) NOT NULL,
`pret` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_campanie` (`id_campanie`),
KEY `cod_produs` (`cod_produs`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
--
-- Constraints for table `stoc`
--
ALTER TABLE `stoc`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `stoc_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_campanie`) REFERENCES `campanii` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `stoc_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_produs`) REFERENCES `produse` (`cod`);
```

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like you may not have a primary key declared for the the Campanii table. Yii relations require the existence of a primary key in order to work. Can you share your SQL table declarations?

Comment: SQL seems good. I have a PK in the parent table and an FK in the child table. I do not have defined a primary key in the models. In my past work it had no influence. I tried to add it but nothing changed.

Comment: There's still no primary key in the `stoc` table.

Comment: I created a PK in `stoc` table. Now it works. But can somebody explain to me why does it requires a primary key? I had to add another column called ID and make it PK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was due to a missing primary key in the `stoc` table. The reason why follows:

```
private function populateRecord($query,$row)
{
    // determine the primary key value
    if(is_string($this->_pkAlias))  // single key
    {
        if(isset($row[$this->_pkAlias]))
            $pk=$row[$this->_pkAlias];
        else    // no matching related objects
            return null;
    }
    else // is_array, composite key
    {
        $pk=array();
        foreach($this->_pkAlias as $name=>$alias)
        {
            if(isset($row[$alias]))
                $pk[$name]=$row[$alias];
            else    // no matching related objects
                return null;
        }
        $pk=serialize($pk);
    }
...
```

The above code is from CActiveFinder. As you can see, if the _pkAlias of a table is not a string, then it assumes it's an array, without checking to see if any primary key exists at all.

Therefore, when you call `with('stocs')`, CActiveFinder tries to populate the related records (meaning, `populateRecord` is called), which tries to figure out the PK as part of its normal process, and so fails due to the lack of a PK.

Ultimately, it is the result of an incorrect assumption in the framework code. It can be worked around (as you found) by simply creating a PK.

You can look at CActiveFinder, starting on line 385, to see how the value of `_pkAlias` is set.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php

Comment: Thank you! I would also like to ask you if there is a possibility to return data from table that is the parent of the child. If you take a look at `stoc` table structure you will see that it is related to another two table. I get data from one of the parents, then with with() method I get the data for the child and I want to obtain the data from the other parent. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Add to your Campannii relations: `'codProdus' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Produse', array('fk_of_produs_in_stoc_table'=>'pk_of_produs_in_produs_table', 'through'=>'stocs')`, making necessary naming adjustments.

Comment: Thank you again! `'produse' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Produse', array('cod_produs'=>'cod'), 'through'=>'stocs'),`

Answer (score 0):

I get same error in CActiveFinder(834) after Yii framework update from 1.1.11 to 1.1.14. All was worked before update, all primary keys was setted.

After some struggling I found that errors is gone when I cleaned my YiiCache (I have CDbCache enabled in my config).

`TRUNCATE YiiCache` or `DELETE FROM YiiCache`